# select values from a table where exclude values in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL Database. I want to get a column values from a table by excluding the values exists in another table.

```
select id from mytable where exclude(select id from another table)
```

In First table available id:

101,102,103,104,105

In second table available id:

101,104

I want result:

```
102,103,105 (excluded values exist in second table)
```

How write Query for this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try

```
select id
from mytable
where id not in (select id from another_table);
```

or

```
select id
from mytable
except
select id
from another_table;
```

Comment: Just a side note: if `ìd` can be null in `another_table`, the first query won't work. In that case a `where id is not null` needs to be added to the sub-select

Answer (score 22):

Using a LEFT JOIN an IS NULL is also an option:

```
SELECT 
  id
FROM 
  mytable
    LEFT JOIN another_table ON mytable.id = another_table.id
WHERE
  another_table.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried solution from "user554546" Not sure what was happening on my example but I had to Select Distinct since once I had two values in another_table then my table would show nonfiltered values twice.

So lets say another_table had

```
|ID|
|03|
|04|
|06|
```

main_table had

```
|ID|
|01|
|02|
|03|
|04|
|05|
|06|
```

After doing the query main_table would show up the following

```
|ID|
|01|
|01|
|01|
|02|
|02|
|02|
|05|
|05|
|05|
```

Distinct seems to solve that but any ideas why was this happening?

Comment: This looks like a question written as an answer. Maybe rewrite it slightly as a separate question with a link to this thread? May be useful for others. :-)